# Component Initialization in Angular: Generic Component

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I'm facing an issue with initializing a `generic component` in my `Angular` application. I think that the ModelListComponent is not being initialized, and the `component` is not initializing with Product Type, here's the relevant code:

*product-registration-screen.component.html:*

```
<div class="row full-height">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <app-product-registration-screen #productRegistration></app-product-registration-screen>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <app-model-list></app-model-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

*ProductRegistrationScreenComponent:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-registration-screen',
  templateUrl: './product-registration-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-registration-screen.component.css']
})
export class ProductRegistrationScreenComponent { 
  
  @ViewChild(ModelListComponent) modelList!: ModelListComponent<Product>;
  @ViewChild(ProductRegistrationComponent) productRegistration!: ProductRegistrationComponent;  
}
```

*ModelListComponent:*

```
export class ModelListComponent<T extends Persistable>
{  
   modelList: T[] = [];
    
   constructor(private crudService: CrudService<T>){}
    
   loadProducts() {
        this.crudService.getAll().subscribe((models) => {
          this.modelList = models;
        });
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the @ViewChild query won't be initialized until after the ngAfterViewInit

create a base class

```
export class BaseModelListComponent<T extends Persistable> {
  modelList: T[] = [];
    
  constructor(protected crudService: CrudService<T>) {}
    
  loadProducts() {
    this.crudService.getAll().subscribe((models) => {
      this.modelList = models;
    });
  }
}
```

then extend this class

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-model-list',
  templateUrl: './model-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./model-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductModelListComponent extends BaseModelListComponent<Product> {
  constructor(crudService: ProductCrudService) {
    super(crudService);
  }
}
```

on your component u can access the model

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.modelList);
  console.log(this.productRegistration);
}
```